# Image re-size to 50% of original size in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, image

I'm trying to re-size a image in HTML, it's got width 314px and height 212px. I want to re-size it to 50%...

but using this I still get a bigger image instead of a half-size image.

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="50%" height="50%" />
```

What did I do wrong?
Thanks

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div>
        <img src="image4.png" width="50%" height="50%"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I resolved the above problem using jquery below:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        var imgLength = imgs.length;

        for(var i=0; i<= imgLength-1;i++){

            var imgWidth = imgs[i].clientWidth;
            var imgHeight = imgs[i].clientHeight;

            $('img').eq(i).attr({width:imgWidth/2, height: imgHeight/2});

            console.log(imgWidth);
        }

        console.log(imgLength); 

    });
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You did not do anything wrong here, it will any other thing that is overriding the image size.

You can check this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb8We/).

And in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb8We/1/) I have alter the image size using `%`, and it is working.

Also try using this code:

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="width: 50%; height: 50%"/>​
```

[Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/pb8We/2/) the example fiddle.

Comment: Does fiddle link I've provided in answer works for you? Can you see the image size difference here? Also do try with `style` attribute as I given

Comment: also fiddle image get bigger when you put 100%, is it relative to div size?

Comment: yeah it's change on fiddle. When inserted 50%

Comment: Interesting..fiddle works for you, but your own code not.. :) and don't worry there is not any problem by `div`..

Comment: hmmm... might be browser problem? but I tried on all the browsers. firefox chrome opera IE also safari...

Comment: Try one thing more, declare the doctype as `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the 1st line of your HTML file, id don't know what is its effect exactly but I observed some changes while playing with this [w3schools-Try it editor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_test) ..

Comment: This resizes image to 50% width of its container, not of original physical width of image itself.

Comment: @MaratTanalin DO you know a way for re-size it to physical width? I noticed with chrome inspect that it evidence the natural size that is correct (314x212) but it shows 823x556.

Comment: @Sam: AFAIK, it's impossible. You always can specify needed pixel dimensions explicitly though.

Answer (score 14):

We can do this by css3 too. Try this:

```
.halfsize {
    -moz-transform:scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.5);
    transform:scale(0.5);
}

<img class="halfsize" src="image4.jpg">
```

- subjected to browser compatibility

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that it leaves whitespace around the element. This is because the way CSS transforms work is this: element is rendered, transform is applied, any other elements around it remain where they were.

Comment: also, this downsizes relative to space around it and not to itself.

Answer (score 11):

The percentage setting does not take into account the original image size.  From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp) :

> In HTML 4.01, the width could be defined in pixels or in % of the containing element. In HTML5, the value must be in pixels.

Also, good practice advice from the same source :

> Tip: Downsizing a large image with the height and width attributes forces a user to download the large image (even if it looks small on the page). To avoid this, rescale the image with a program before using it on a page.

Comment: Regarding good practice, there are legitimate reasons for wanting client size resizing. Anti-aliasing for example.

Comment: maybe so, but - no retina support

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `x` descriptor of the `srcset` attribute as such:

```html
<!-- Original image -->
<img src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia.png" />

<!-- With a 80% size reduction (1/0.8=1.25) -->
<img srcset="https://fr.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia.png 1.25x" />

<!-- With a 50% size reduction (1/0.5=2) -->
<img srcset="https://fr.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia.png 2x" />
```

Currently supported by all browsers except IE. ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/srcset))

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset)